# Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager'

Tags: java, xml, spring, junit, ehcache

Trying to run a unit test on a Controller in my Spring app.

My test class:

```
@RunWith (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration ({"classpath*:WEB-INF/spring/application-context-config.xml", "data-source-test-config.xml", 
                        "classpath*:WEB-INF/spring/security-context-config.xml"})
public class PropsControllerTest
```

The error I'm getting:

```
2015-04-03 23:22:51.729 WARN  AbstractApplicationContext:487 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cacheManager' is defined
```

My application-context-config.xml defines:

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"/>
</bean>
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
    <property name="shared" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

ehcache.xml Defines:

```
<ehcache>
    <cache name="backslap"
           maxBytesLocalHeap="256M"
           eternal="false"
           timeToLiveSeconds="3600"
           overflowToDisk="false"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>
</ehcache>
```

I've got copies of ehcache.xml in three places: src/main/resources/, test/main/resources/ and in the directory of my test class.  Nothing fixes this problem.

How do I make Spring find the file during testing (it has no problem finding the file when running)?  Failing that, how do I make Spring stop wanting this information (the cache is utterly worthless during my tests), or at least let me just specify it in my application-context-config.xml file?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you have a cacheManager bean defined anywhere? You might be declaring the ehcache, but that is not also defining the cacheManager bean that spring is trying to find.

Comment: check your xml file where this cacheManager is defined & add it to context configuration.Problem clearly says spring was unable to find the bean.if requires you can edit your question & post config xml as part of your question.

Comment: did that help with the issue ?

Comment: I gave up on org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager and switched to org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager which solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
 No bean named 'cacheManager' is defined
```

This error is due to Spring not being able to identify this bean.

Identify the file where this bean is defined, and make sure it's available for the test context.